# how to sort an ArrayList by its objects properties?

Tags: java, android

Say I have an ArrayList of custom object, such as

```
class fileOjb
{
    String path;
    String format;
    int size;
    int dateadd;
}
```

How should I sort it by
- path, format, size or dateadded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code example.for sorting by `dateAdded`.
for sorting by other properties..you have to first decide your `criteria`.
(what is criteria for String `path1` to be greater than `path2`)

```
public class MyComparableByDateAdded implements Comparator<fileOjb>{

    @Override
    public int compare(fileOjb o1, fileOjb o2) {
        return (o1.dateAdd>o2.dateAdd ? -1 : (o1.dateAdd==o2.dateAdd ? 0 : 1));
    }
}

Collections.sort(list, new MyComparableByDateAdded());
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to write your own [comparator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm) and call Collections.sort(yourComparator)

For example:

```
class YourComparator implements Comparator<MyObj>{

   public int compare(MyObj o1, MyObj o2) {
        return o1.getyourAtt() - o2.getyourAtt();
    }

}

NOTE: Cast o1 and 02 to your object type.
EDIT: Based on Ted comment, update to generics, now don't need cast
```

Comment: but @thinksteep how can I do that without a code example :)

Comment: @Frank Sposaro [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

Comment: It would be better to use generic types rather than raw types and casts.

Comment: @kw4nta your link didn't work. I was perfectly fine with the just implement Comparator answer. But I saw pleading for code being the next thing asked.

Comment: @FrankSposaro: Added all relevant and required references.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a `Comparator<fileObj>` and sort the list using `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`; method